# How to call backtrace_symbols() in Swift

Tags: swift, backtrace

In Objective-C, I can call the code to get backtrace

```c
void* callstack[128];
int frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
char **strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);
```

by import `#include <execinfo.h>`

but in Swift, how can I call `backtrace` and `backtrace_symbols`, I can't find `execinfo` file any where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can print the stack backtrace simply with
(from [How to print call stack in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754796/how-to-print-call-stack-in-swift/39633262#39633262)):

```
for symbol in Thread.callStackSymbols {
    print(symbol)
}
```

But if you are curious how to translate the C code to Swift:
First add

```
#include <execinfo.h>
```

to the bridging header file to make the `backtrace()` function
available. Then note that `void *` corresponds to 
`UnsafeMutableRawPointer?` in Swift, and you are almost done:

```
var callstack = [UnsafeMutableRawPointer?](repeating: nil, count: 128)
let frames = backtrace(&callstack, Int32(callstack.count))
if let symbols = backtrace_symbols(&callstack, frames) {
    for frame in 0..<Int(frames) where symbols[frame] != nil {
        let symbol = String(cString: symbols[frame]!)
        print(symbol)
    }
    free(symbols)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```swift
@_silgen_name("backtrace")
internal func swift_backtrace(_ callstacks: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, _ counts: Int) -> Int

@_silgen_name("backtrace_symbols")
internal func swift_backtrace_symbols(_ callstacks: UnsafeRawPointer, _ counts: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<CChar>>?


var callstack = [UnsafeMutableRawPointer?](repeating: nil, count: 128)
let frames = swift_backtrace(&callstack, callstack.count)

if let symbols = swift_backtrace_symbols(&callstack, frames) {
    for frame in 0..<frames {
        let symbol = String(cString: symbols[frame])
        print(symbol)
    }
    
    free(symbols)
}
```