# Getting the stack trace of the error origin in swift

Tags: swift

Consider this code:

```
func doSomething() throws {
  try callThrowingFunction1()
  try callThrowingFunction2()
}

func userAction() {
  do {
    try doSomething()
  } catch {
    // display and log error
  }
}
```

Say those inner functions can throw the same kind of errors and I would like to know if an error occurred in `callThrowingFunction1()` or in `callThrowingFunction2()`.

As long as I'm in the debugger I can set a breakpoint for Swift errors on `swift_willThrow`, but if I would like to log the call stack on a user device, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Are those functions implemented by you or coming from a system/3rd party API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754796/how-to-print-call-stack-in-swift ?

Comment: By me, but I would like to have some generic method.

Comment: @Larme, yes, I know how to get the stack trace at some point in the code, but then I would have to insert code to get the stack trace at any place that calls `throw`.

Comment: You can use two different Do-Catch blocks, one for each `try`. Each one will have its own `catch` so you can know where the error came from.

Comment: You can also throw your own error from your own functions, including a custom `Dictionary` as the `userInfo` property of the error, where you can include all relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

`Swift` errors have no such thing as stack-trace yet (if will ever), and even `Xcode` can show stack-trace **only** if the error is un-handled by our code (and gets caught by Xcode directly instead).

Alternativly, your custom `Error`'s constructor can store the stack-trace for later use, but in most cases errors are not custom, where you can't alter error's constructor (like errors of 3rd-party library).

---

But we can at least print stack-trace of where error(s) get catched, like:

```swift
do {
    try ... // something that throws goes here
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error)")

    println(NSThread.callStackSymbols())
}
```

### Exception breakpoint

If you just want to debug, without need to upload stack-trace to server, then Xcode's "Exception breakpoint" feature can help, like:

- First place a normal-breakpoint near the failing logic.
- Wait until Xcode pauses App on that line, enable Xcode's feature:

  [image]

  [image]
- Finally, resume App, and wait untill exception is thrown.

> Images are old, nowadays you see "Add Swift Error Breakpoint" or something like that as well (beside "Add Exception Breakpoint" option).